# C# SSH into Server A and SFTP upload to Server B (using SSH.NET)

Tags: c#, linux, ssh, sftp, file-transfer

I have a desktop application that's connecting to a Linux VPS via SSH that contains files that need to be uploaded to another server. Is this something I can do with SSH.NET or any other library? Or should I maybe go with the inefficient route of first downloading the files locally then initiating an SFTP connection to the server I need to upload to? Or maybe there's something completely different I should be doing - I'm open to suggestions.

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: How can you connect to the other server? Over SSH as well? Or over FTP? Could you try just running an `scp` command on your VPS?

Comment: I've used SSH.NET for this at my previous job to push files to another server.  I would suggest this library if you need to create a quick little app.

Comment: To connect to the other server that I'm uploading to I need to connect via sftp. The only other drawback for me at this point is my lack of Linux command line experience. If I can execute a command via ssh to do this then that would probably work for me too.

Comment: @JohnDoe SSH.NET and Renci.SshNet is the same library (first is library name, latter is library namespace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in SSH/SFTP that would help you implementing a file transfer between two *remote servers*. So SSH.NET library won't help you much with that either.

All it can do for you, is to execute the same shell commands (`sftp`) on server A that you use manually to upload the files to B.

Comment: I had a feeling that might be the case. I'm trying to separate some internal processes (including this task) from a public facing web application that would not necessarily need to be part of the web application. I think I'll opt to download the files from server A, and ftp upload to server B after... seems a little clunky, but it'll work. Might experiment with the shell commands while I'm at it too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I opted to do the following:

1. SSH into server through the desktop application
2. Send an scp command to run a .net core console app on the server
3. App on server performs ftp upload along with any other tasks I wanted to perform in the process.